# Wrong date returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql, express

I'm just looking for help for a json answer.

When I use a query on my postgres DB, I got this results:

```
select sum(total_value), CAST(date_start AS DATE) 
  from result 
 where DATE(date_start) BETWEEN '2019-07-11' AND '2019-07-18' 
 group by CAST(date_start AS DATE) 
 order by CAST(date_start AS DATE);
```

```
"16.81" "2019-07-11"
"15.42" "2019-07-12"
"40.08" "2019-07-15"
"11.45" "2019-07-16"
"91.52" "2019-07-17"
"25.34" "2019-07-18"
```

But if I try in nodejs with pg module:

```
app.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
  var date = new Date()
  var lastWeek = new Date();
  lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate()-7)
  date1 = date.getFullYear() +"-"+ (date.getMonth()+1) +"-"+ date.getDate()
  date2 = lastWeek.getFullYear() +"-"+ (lastWeek.getMonth()+1) +"-"+ lastWeek.getDate()
  console.log(date1, date2)
  pool.query('select sum(total_value), CAST(date_start AS DATE) from result where DATE(date_start) BETWEEN '2019-07-11' AND '2019-07-18' GROUP BY CAST(date_start AS DATE) ORDER BY CAST(date_start AS DATE)', 
  (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    res.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
})
```

I got this JSON answer:

```
[{"sum":"16.81","date_start":"2019-07-10T22:00:00.000Z"}, 
{"sum":"15.42","date_start":"2019-07-11T22:00:00.000Z"}, 
{"sum":"40.08","date_start":"2019-07-14T22:00:00.000Z"}, 
{"sum":"11.45","date_start":"2019-07-15T22:00:00.000Z"}, 
{"sum":"91.52","date_start":"2019-07-16T22:00:00.000Z"}, 
{"sum":"25.34","date_start":"2019-07-17T22:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Why in the result I have different days ?

Comment: Those timestamps are two hours off, reflecting GMT+2 I guess. I assume you're requesting this with AJAX? How exactly are you printing the result?

Comment: Your database shows you the local time and the JSON result is in UTC. If you have to support multiple timezones in one database, it's usually a good idea to save everything as UTC and do the conversion to local time on the client side, since due to daylight savings time, not every local date is unique, while the notation UTC uses is by design.

Comment: @ChrisG I only open my web browser with localhost:3000/getData

Comment: @Shilly I don't have to support multiple timezones in this database. I cant afford to change all the databases of all servers. Is there a way to update the timezone before send it ?

Comment: Use the correct SQL command to turn it into local time notation if you need the json response to have the local timestamp. Or use `new Date()` and locales instead of the UTC variants on the client. The default behaviour is to use local time. SO if you only need local time you do not have an issue, since `new Date( "2019-07-10T22:00:00.000Z" ).toString() === "Thu Jul 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)"` if your locale is Central Euro Time. So you can just ignore the problem providing you use the correct Date methods on the client.

Comment: @Shilly thx, it solves the problem